# giving a variable a value from specific row and column in a dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to set the value of a variable (x) to be the MP.Minutes.Played for a certain player (player) of my choice.

```
player = Aaron Ramsey
x = MP.Minutes.Played #of# player
```

Any help would be much appreciated !!

[image: Data Frame]

Comment: It is difficult to tell what you are asking. Please consider providing a minimal reproducible example with your desired output: [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, images are discouraged, versus posting the data as text.

Comment: `x = your_data[your_data$Player.Name = player, "MP.MinutesPlayed"]`.

Comment: Please see also [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html) and many other resources available in the[R Tag WIki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: @Gregor `==` instead of `=`

Comment: Whoops, too late to edit so I'll repost the comment corrected: `x = your_data[your_data$Player.Name == player, "MP.MinutesPlayed"]`

Comment: This seems like it should be a dupe, but I can't find anything quite this basic: "how to subset a data frame" - all the matching questions seem to have complicating elements. Might be worth doing a comprehensive write-up on simple subsets and turning it into an R-Faq? Unless someone can find a nice dupe...

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Gregor

x = your_data[your_data$Player.Name = player, "MP.MinutesPlayed"]. – Gregor 16 mins ago